# Why doesn't this loop terminate?

Tags: java, recursion, collatz

Here's the sample code:

```
public static void col (int n) 
{
    if (n % 2 == 0) 
       n = n/2 ; 
    if (n % 2 != 0) 
       n = ((n*3)+1) ;

    System.out.println (n) ;
    if (n != 1) 
       col (n) ;
}
```

this works just fine until it gets down to 2. then it outputs `2 4 2 4 2 4 2 4 2 4` infinitely. it seems to me that if 2 is entered as n then `(n % 2 == 0)` is true 2 will be divided by 2 to yeild 1. then 1 will be printed and since `(n != 1)` is false the loop will terminate.

Why doesn't this happen?

Comment: This is recursion, not a loop.

Comment: if you indent your code properly it is easier to spot logic bugs like this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in addition to an `else if` to govern the condition that n is odd that same line also needs `& n != 1` to be added to it within the conditional. So this:

```
else if (n % 2 != 0 & n != 1)
```

Answer (score 13):

Because when you get to 1, you are multiplying by 3 and adding 1, taking you back to 4.

You need an ELSE in there. I don't know java, but it would look something like:

```
public static void col (int n) 
{
    if (n % 2 == 0) 
      n = n/2 ; 
    else if (n % 2 != 0) 
      n = ((n*3)+1) ;

    System.out.println (n) ;
    if (n != 1) 
      col (n) ;
}
```

EDIT: as mentioned in the comments, you can omit the if test after the else:

```
if (n % 2 == 0) 
  n = n/2 ; 
else 
  n = ((n*3)+1) ;
```

Comment: You could just say `else`, since the condition in the `else if` is guaranteed to be true. But otherwise, you got it all right, despite apparently not knowing Java. :-)

Comment: @Chris: Good point. Also, there's no particular reason to implement this recursively, except as an exercise. A while loop would be especially preferable if the language doesn't do tail call optimization.

Comment: Maybe the OP translated it from Scheme! (Unlikely, but had to say it anyway. :-P)

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll have to change the 2nd `if` statement to an `else`

```
if (n % 2 == 0)      // if the n is even
  n = n/2 ; 
else                 // if n is odd
  n = ((n*3)+1) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question can be read directly in the code:

```
Assume n is 2
(n % 2 == 0) is true therefore n <- 1
(n % 2 != 0) is also true therefore 4 <- n

this warrants a call to function with n = 4,  which is then changed to 2 and
"back to square 1"
```

by **replacing the second test by an else**, you solve this logic problem, at the cost of possibly causing more recursion  (since in the current logic, two operations are sometimes performed in one iteration).  Such a fix will **also solve a more subtle bug**, which is that in the current version not all new values of n are printed out.

Now, for extra credit, prove that not matter the initial value of n, the number of recursions is finite (i.e. the sequence converges to 1).  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use if/then/else. Your logic is wrong.

Comment: sorry, but it is homework and it would be pointless to simply give you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

when the input is 2:

```
if (n % 2 == 0)         //true
  n = n/2;              //n = 1 
if (n % 2 != 0)         //true
  n = ((n*3)+1);        //n = 4

System.out.println (n); //prints 4
if (n != 1)             //true
  col (n);              //call col(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you change it to this?

```
if (n % 2 == 0) 
    n = n/2 ; 
else if (n % 2 != 0) 
    n = ((n*3)+1) ;
```

It looks like you're getting 2, dividing by 2 to get 1, then checking to see if 1/2 has a remainder (it does), and multiplying it by 3 and adding 1, to get 4....

Answer (score 0):

if (n % 2 != 0) 
       n = ((n*3)+1) ;

this code is again implemented whenever u get 1.

therefore the recursive function will be called repeatedly hence leading to an infinite rec calling and code will never terminate.